# Acumatica Report Custom Page Size

Tags: acumatica

How do I get the largest or custom page size in Acumatica to work on a report? I attached a screenshot of the settings screen, but nothing seems to work.
Thank you,[image]

Comment: Have you modified the report itself to use this papersize?

Comment: how do i modify the general reports (not designed in acumatica design viewer) to utilize the custom page size?